# what is the safe way to notify parent process in signal handler?

Tags: linux, signals

When my child process crash, it need a lot of time to do coredump (because I dump hugepages) and then the parent got SIGCHLD, but it is too late for me. So I use signal handler in child process to notify parent process and then do coredump, I just want to send the child pid to parent process. But I am not sure which mechanism is safe in this case. pipe or ipc message queue or unix socket?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough details, but I assume in almost all the languages that allow you to explicitly spawn a new process there is a mechanism to get the child PID right when it gets created.
For example in C when you call **fork()** if the child process is created successfully it returns the child PID.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I choose POSIX message queue finally, though it may be unsafe to call mq_send() in signal handler.